# Why is an almost complex structure $J$ a tensor field of type $(1,1)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I've just read that for an almost-complex manifold $(M^{2n},J)$ the almost-complex structure $J:TM\to TM$ can be understood as a tensor field of type $(1,1)$.

I don't get it.

According to the section "Using tensor poducts" from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) wikipedia article, a tensor $T$ of type $(1,1)$ would belong to $V\otimes V^*$, so in our case, $J_p\in T_pM\otimes T_pM^*$.

But $J_p$ is by definition a linear map from $T_pM$ to itself, so $J_p\in \text{End}(T_pM)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes there is a canonical identification there. You can prove it pointwise. For any vector space $V$, try constructing a natural map $V\otimes V^*\to \operatorname{End}(V)$. Then prove that it is surjective, and therefore injective (by dimension comparison). Also this can be generalized to $W\otimes V^*\to \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$. (Which might help you think through how to construct the map).

Comment: All you need to know is that $V^*\otimes W\cong L(V,W)$ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If with respect to a coordinate system $(x^j)$ on $M$ you write $J(\partial_j) = \sum J^i_{~j}\partial_i$, then $J$ can be regarded as $$J = \sum J^i_{~j}\,{\rm d}x^j \otimes \partial_i,$$acting on vector fields by $$X \mapsto J(X) = \sum J^i_{~j}{\rm d}x^j(X)\partial_i.$$There is nothing particular about manifolds or almost-complex structures here. In general, in the level of vector spaces we have the (natural) isomorphism $$V^*\otimes W \ni f\otimes w \mapsto (v \mapsto f(v)w) \in {\rm Hom}(V,W),$$whose inverse can be described in terms of a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$ (with dual basis $(e^i)$) by $${\rm Hom}(V,W) \ni T \mapsto \sum e^i\otimes T(e_i) \in V^*\otimes W.$$

Comment: (nit-picking:) at the level of *finite dimensional* vector spaces ;)